# QuickBooks Online SalesReceipt Api and multiple payment methods

Tags: quickbooks-online

How do I add multiple payment methods to a sales receipt in quickbooks?

Here is the document:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/salesreceipt

PaymentMethodRef just allows for one reference. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation, a `Sales Receipt` in QuickBooks only has a single payment method.

If someone paid for a single order in two ways, you could either:

1. Create two separate sales receipts (one for each payment method)
2. Create an invoice, and apply two separate payments against it